# Using Ibus (Japanese input) with Ubuntu Mate and i3

Tags: keyboard, keyboard-layout, mate, ibus

I am currently using Ubuntu Mate (18.04 LTS) with the i3 tiling manager and want to add Japanese input.

I installed Ibus like this:
`sudo apt-get install ibus ibus-anthy`

Whenever I enter the setup using `ibus-setup` and try to change the keyboard shortcuts I get the following error message:

`(ibus-setup:10367): Gdk-CRITICAL **: 21:40:09.983: gdk_window_get_window_type: assertion 'GDK_IS_WINDOW (window)' failed`

Any help on how to get this running would be greatly appreciated. Ibus is not a strict requirement for me, I just want to be able to write in Japanese (and Chinese).

**edit:** I should add that switching languages works as long as I do not use the i3 window manager.

**edit:** It works using fcitx:

```
1. sudo apt install fcitx fcitx-googlepinyin fcitx-mozc im-config
2. use im-config to select fcitx
3. reboot
4. use fcitx-config-gtk3 to add languages/shortcuts
```